# How to restore the SQL backup by mysqldump --all-databases?

Tags: mysql, backup

So I have backed all my databases up with this:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > all.sql
```

My question is how to restore all.sql to mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've included the CREATE TABLE lines,

```
mysql -uroot -p < all.sql
```